# Can't access a global variable in PHP-"Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object"

Tags: php, global-variables, fatal-error

There are a number of Q's on this topic but I wasn't able to get it to work…thanks in advance for any and all help you can give.

Basically, I'm trying to do an AJAX call and it is working successfully. The call is made to a file named stores.php. Within that file, the following function is called:

```
function function1($ABC){
  echo "…";
  ...
  $var = function2($DEF);
  … //do stuff with var 
}
```

The trouble crops up in function2:

```
function function2($GHI){
  global $db;
  $query ='SELECT …';
  … // more...
  $results = $db->query($query);
  return $results;
}
```

For the query() call to $db, I get the error: "Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object…"

I don't really understand this because I am inviting it into the function with 'global'. In some of the other Q's, people discussed some sort of scoping problem when a function is called from within another function that I didn't really understand, but I thought the point was that the function gets its predecessors scope. So I went around declaring it global wherever I could think of that would be relevant, and it didn't work.

I even re-included the script that originally created the $db variable in that function, and it still felt it was null!

NOTE: PLease keep in mind that the file, stores.php contains many functions that all successfully use "global $db" in making queries of the db.
Thanks again...

Comment: try `var_dump($db)` to see what value the variable has

Comment: The result is a resounding "NULL"

Comment: Then somewhere between you setting the variable, and you using it, it's being re-set.

Comment: Ok, I guess that makes sense, but how would something like that happen? Every function in that file can use it. When I am generating the area that makes the ajax call, those functions are called and they work. And then suddenly I make the call from an AJAX function and it's unset? 
Obviously, I'm not unsetting it somewhere explicitly…are there implicit ways to unset a variable?

Comment: Generally, it'll be reset because you explicitly set a value; the other option would be that it's not being set in the first place. Try adding some debugging after you open the database connection to see if it's being set properly.

Comment: Well, I know it's being set properly because all the other functions use "global $db" and are able to access it just fine. And I don't think I am _explicitly_ resetting it (I hope I would remember that!)

Comment: Do you close the connection somewhere? Really, there's not much more help we can be without looking at the actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was very simple, but also very specific to my page. Basically, stores.php (the file which contained the functions) was being included [via include()] to a main page. Earlier in that page, the variable $db was being set. Therefore, all the functions that were written in the stores.php page were able to access $db once it was declared with 'global'.

But when I was making the call that was failing, I was calling the function from stores.php directly--not the main page. And on that page, $db isn't ever created at all! So it was null.

Answer (score -1):

SInce you are using a variable which is global, make sure that none of your functions that use global $db, will not overwrite it. Best way for making sure, if the global $db actually is object, is to use print_r($db) inside the function where that exception gets thrown.

Comment: @Jo.P: That means it's a number, not an object.  If it's *supposed* to be an object, then something along the way has messed it up.  Reason #153 to avoid mutable global state.

Comment: Now you have to track your code, where does ur global variable get overwritten. 

If my answer helped you solve your issue, then please accept my answer. Stackoverflow is full of questions which have been solved but not accepted. Thanks

Comment: I gave it a plus one bec it helped show what the problem was, but I hope to explain what the issue really was in my own post.

Comment: @Jo.P - Lauri was just trying to help you. If you need help understanding, all you need to do is ask for more details. There's no need to be rude to those who offer assistance.

Comment: @jww-I didn't mean to be rude at all, I'm sorry if it sounded like that. All I meant is that while it's true that $db wasn't set, it was a very different issue than an overwrite. I put up an answer that explains it in detail. The answer was helpful, but it didn't really answer the question as much as say the question ("why is it a non-obkect?") in different words.. So I gave it a plus 1.